# Editing partition image

Tags: partitions, mount, images, imei

My Samsung phone lost its IMEI number. As far as i know it stored in /efs/sec_efs/SVC és !SVC files.

These files cannot be edited during running. My idea is that i "dd"-ed the efs partition to an image file, then i would edit these two text files, then restore the efs partition from the image with ODIN (It's similar to fastboot mode on other brands).

How can i edit the partition image file?

1. I wanted to mount the image file on the phone with ADB as a normal writeable partition, then edit the SVC files. But how can i mount it?
2. Mount the image file on Windows like CD/DVD/etc image files, then edit the text files. But how can i mount or edit the image file? Is there a working application for this?
3. There are lots of IMEI editor apps, but i can not trust these random apps from the net.
4. Any other idea to restore the IMEI?

(I know it's illegal to change IMEI. I don't want to change it, i want to restore the factory assigned IMEI.)

Comment: `mount` is a linux coreutil. use linux

Comment: Yes try mounting onto loop devices. A "dd-ed" partition image is different from a non dd-ed. Thats why its not recommended to magisk patch an extraxted partition image and flash it again. How about trying to get a new firmware and edit the new stock image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerIso can open the Android image files.
https://www.poweriso.com/